# Protobuf and Non-blocking message send/recv

Tags: c++, sockets, streaming, protocol-buffers, libevent

I am developing my message passing interface using `protobuf` and non-blocking `libevent` socket libraries. Because of the non-blocking properties, the read callback by `libevent` might be invoked at some points where the messages are not complete (e.g., every 4096 bytes received). This means I have to write another wrapper/header indicating the size of each message so I can parse the message back to the `protobuf` object correctly. Are there better solutions for this? Or does `protobuf` provide an API to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no better solution. In fact, even when using blocking I/O, you need to write a header indicating the size, because Protobufs are not self-delimiting (by default the protobuf parser will always read until EOF!).

Comment: OK. I got it. Thank you!